# Memory leak when adding uint32_t to a queue in a different namespace

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am attempting to flag objects for database update in namespace 'api' by pushing their unique id numbers to a queue within the databases namespace. This is done through the function flagObjectToUpdate also in the namespace 'database'.

When testing the code below with cppUTest I get a number of memory leaks, I am totally stumped as to how this would cause a leak. I have narrow it down to the code below by commenting out all other lines of code in the call stack.

Could anyone provide some insight?

```
namespace api
{
    uint32_t setObjVal(uint32_t objNumber, uint32_t objVal, uint32_t source)
    {
        // set object values
        if(source == EXTERNAL_WRITE)
            dataBase::flagObjectsToUpdate(objNumber);
        return result;
    }
}

namespace database
{
    std::queue<uint32_t> objNumQueue;

    void flagObjectsToUpdate(uint32_t objNumber)
    {
        objNumQueue.push(objNumber);
    }

    uint32_t updateObject(void)
    {
        uint32_t objNum;
        while(!objNumQueue.empty())
        {
            objNum = objNumQueue.front();
            objNumQueue.pop();
            //update objects       
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any UB or memory violation in the code, per se. Probably this snippet is not sufficient in order to determine the bug.

Comment: There is no leak in this code, so it has to be in code you have not shown.  My magic crystal ball debugger suggests your source files are probably operating on separate `std::queue` objects in the same namespace - one source file pushing values into one `std::queue` object, and another source file popping values from a different `std::queue` object.

Comment: I suspect your global object `objNumQueue` is destroyed after memleak report.

Comment: You have an `objectNumQueue` symbol and an `objNumQueue`.  Where is `objectNumQueue` defined?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo, `objectNumQueue` and `objNumQueue` should be the same, I have edited the question to reflect this. Thanks @all for the insight.

Comment: This is not an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and has no obvious problems, so the problem is in the other code you don't show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to determine a root cause, however, I was able to solve the memory leak by placing the queue, flagObjectsToUpdate(), and updateObject() into a class.

I suspect user Jarod42 was correct when he stated that the memory leak report was posted before the queue object was destroyed.